# Set Ruby on Rails cookie in Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

Is there a way to set a cookie of a Rails application "outside" of said application. I have a rake task running that's just a simple Ruby script. The Ruby script is "called" via `require`, so I'm in the Rails namespace already. The rake task simply looks as such:

```
task :websocket_server => :environment do
    libpath = Rails.root.join('lib', 'script_directory')
   require "#{libpath}/script"
end
```

So for instance, I can use `debugger` inside that Ruby script. However, I can't use the `cookies` method. Do I have to `require` something or make that script inherit from a certain class so that I can use `cookies`? Is there a different method that can get and set cookies?

Ideally, I would like to set and get cookies through static methods. Unfortunately I don't  know whether this is a possiblity at all.

I'm using Rails 5.

Comment: Can you please explain what you try to achieve and why you think that you need a cookie in e script? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Answer (score 0):

That is the [`cookies`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie):

> An HTTP cookie (also called web cookie, Internet cookie, browser
>   cookie, or simply cookie) is a small piece of data sent **from a website**
>   and stored on the user's computer by the user's web browser while the user is browsing.

You're using `rake` task, the `rake` task does nothing with web-server.